# How to save value from class in TextCtrl

Tags: c++, class, wxwidgets

I'm trying to print the result of oblicz.suma(rzeczywiste,urojone) in TextCtrl5.

I'm getting error:

```
cannot convert 'Zespolona' to double in initialization
```

My code:

```
struct Zespolona
{
    double re {0.0};
    double im {0.0};
};

class Obliczenia
{
public:
    Zespolona suma( const Zespolona& a, const Zespolona& b )
    {
        return { a.re + b.re, a.im + b.im };
    }

};

void Zad2Frame::OnButton1Click(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    Obliczenia oblicz;
    wxString rzecz1 = TextCtrl1->GetValue();
    wxString uroj1 = TextCtrl2->GetValue();
    wxString rzecz2 = TextCtrl3->GetValue();
    wxString uroj2 = TextCtrl4->GetValue();
    double drzecz1 = atof(rzecz1);
    double duroj1 = atof(uroj1);
    double drzecz2 = atof(rzecz2);
    double duroj2 = atof(uroj2);

    Zespolona rzeczywiste {drzecz1,drzecz2};
    Zespolona urojone {duroj1,duroj2};
    Zespolona liczba_suma = oblicz.suma(rzeczywiste,urojone);
    
    wxString wynik = oblicz.suma(rzeczywiste,urojone);
    TextCtrl5->SetValue(wynik);
}
```

I've tried to save value to wxString and then print this variable using TextCtrl5->SetValue(mywxString) with similar error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people who have a similar problem.

```
wxString wynik;
    wynik.Printf("%.f+%.fi",  liczba_suma.re, liczba_suma.im);
    TextCtrl5->SetValue(wynik );
```